# Strange black box apears and input slows down

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, performance

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS yesterday on my old laptop and it worked great but after some time a strange black box appeared on screen and the input slowed down a lot, like I press a key and it is reflected after 5-10 seconds. After some time the box disappeared and everything went back to normal but then after a couple of hours it happened again.

First I thought it to be random but then I noticed it happens when I use the keyboard to type something, not every time I use the keyboard but whenever it appears I am generally using the keyboard in my browser. It appears on the middle part of the bottom half of the screen with an unavailable type sign on it.

As I installed Ubuntu yesterday I haven't installed many things... just some gnome extensions and a failed install of BSD games.

I am a new user I don't know much about Linux much.

I used an Asus laptop(X553SA (ASUS-NotebookSKU)) for it with 4GB Ram and a 4-core Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3700 with a speed of 1.6Ghz

I don't know if the problem is with my device or the Firefox browser

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer? Does your machine have a "tablet mode"?

Comment: I did it and I don't think it has a Tablet Mode

Comment: That symbol means that some key is being pressed where it has no function. If you aren't pressing any then you have a defective keyboard. It could be due to the non user removable battery swallowing.

Comment: Ok Thank You but what is Non User removable battery swallowing ? And can you please tell me if it is possible to detect which key is being pressed by the defective keyboard ?